# Is there a newer version of the ServiceStack ProtoBufServiceClient example?

Tags: servicestack, protobuf-net

I'm using 4.0.60 of ServiceStack and wanted to implement a service client to use Protobuf format, I tried this [example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format) from the docs, but the underlying ServiceClientBase has evolved and this code no longer will compile. Is there another example of a working solution, or is there a prepackaged ServiceStack client for consuming Protobuf?

**Update**

After digging around a bit it looks like the client comes bundled with the [ServiceStack Protobuf nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.ProtoBuf)

Thank you,
Stephen